# How would you design this MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am a building a blog/forum type website from scratch and I'm wondering how to best design the database. The website is going to have posts, comments and comment threading (reply to a reply).

Posts and comments obviously share a lot of the same attributes so I'm leaning towards just storing content in single table called 'posts'. Say the basic gist of this table is:

- id
- body
- author
- timestamp

Now, what I'd love some ideas on is what would be the optimal relationship tables and/or additional columns to flag which posts are threads and which are comments, and then which are comments are at the root level of a thread vs which are in response to another comment.

If any relational database experts can chime in, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most basic structure is this:

```
post 1----* comment *---
                1      |
                 -------
```

where a post may have many comments, comments can have parent comments and comments can have multiple child comments.

Hope this helps.